# How do I connect or share one USB headset with two laptops running windows?

Tags: headset, wireless-headset, logitech-headset, usb-headset

Looking for a solution to share one USB headset between two laptop computers running windows such that I can attend meetings on both the computers without plugging in and out the USB headset.

Comment: something in https://www.amazon.com/s?k=KVM+Switches+usb should do it (e.g. perhaps https://www.amazon.com/Plugable-Sharing-One-Button-Swapping-Computers/dp/B00JX3Q28Y at a glance, not sure though); check the product descriptions and reviews. also https://www.google.com/search?q=usb+ab+switch looks promising.

Comment: You don’t; There are USB switches that might be acceptable, but it’s impossible to get audio from two different hosts, if your using a USB headset

Comment: Are the two computers physically far apart? Perhaps you could connect the line out of the first PC to the line in of the second PC